# Safari can't verify the identity of the website error

Tags: safari, macos

When I upgraded macOS to Sierra last month, I started getting this error on a few websites (Lifehacker, Xkcd, etc).  When I try to read anything on Lifehacker, I get a particularly odd version of this error which says "Safari can't verify the identity of the website Kinja.com"  ...but my link is for lifehacker.com

As I said, when I first upgraded to Sierra, I got the error...  but a restart seemed to clear it up and I didn't get the error again until today when I updated to 10.12.1 and a restart didn't fix it (which makes sense.  I don't know why a restart fixed it last time).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Kinja powers the discussions on former Gawker Media sites including lifehacker.com. If there's a problem with the security certificate on kinja.com that could cause that error.

Comment: Wouldn't lots of people be seeing this same error then?  Also: I'm getting a similar error on Xkcd.com, minus the mention of Kinja.

Comment: I have no idea what the actual issue is or how many people are affected, I'm just explaining why you might see an error about kinja.com when browsing lifehacker.com.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue as well. When you get the error, expand it and change the dropdowns to "Always Trust." That should fix it.

Comment: I would recommend *never* trusting a problematic certificate, unless you understand the problem and know that it's not a security threat. A certificate error might be due to some harmless bit of misconfiguration on a server... or it might be someone trying to steal your credentials (and thence identity, money, etc). If you don't know how to tell the difference, trusting a problematic certificate is *dangerous*.